# Junit Test for jersey (RESTful) @POST html form

Tags: junit, http-post, jersey

I am trying to write a junit test case for the method below:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("writeStuff")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public Response stuffToWrite(FormDataMultiPart formData) {
     ....
}
```

How do I simulate the html form? I am thinking

```
 MultiPart multipart = new FormDataMultiPart();
```

But I don't know how to populate it with fields and data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

See Multipart-Webapp sample from Jersey workspace: https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/releases/com/sun/jersey/samples/multipart-webapp/1.9.1/multipart-webapp-1.9.1-gf-project.zip

There is a test class which does what you need: [MultipartWebAppTest.java](http://java.net/projects/jersey/sources/svn/content/trunk/jersey/samples/multipart-webapp/src/test/java/com/sun/jersey/samples/multipart/MultipartWebAppTest.java?rev=5399)